# UIScrollView temporarily gets fractured when presented from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have `UITableView` with items. When you click on an item, `UIScrollView` is presented inside a `UIViewController` which is being pushed on the `UINavigationController's` stack. While this thing is happening some parts of `UIScrollView` are shown, while others gets transparent showing the initial `UITableView` items. The `UIScrollView` is set up in `.xib`, as the top most superview:

[image]

I tried to put `UIScrollView` inside `UIView`, but it just leads to disappearance of everything and I see a blank screen, although I tried setting up scrollviews' size in code.

So, my goal is to prevent this fracturing of the views happening during the transition from `UITableView` to `UIScrollView`. It seems to be specifically related to the fact that I am presenting `UIScrollView`, since it never happened to me when presenting just a regular `UIView`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are presenting UIScrollView in same view ?

Comment: No, it is a different controller. I actually just solved it by putting all of the `subviews` of the `scrollView` into a completely new `UIView` that I dragged onto the canvas from `Object Library` in `Interface Builder`, and then putting this `UIView` inside the `scrollView`. One thing that is important is `NOT` to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the `subviews` of the `scrollView` into a completely new `UIView` that was dragged onto the canvas from `Object Library` in `Interface Builder`, and then put this `UIView` inside the `scrollView`.
Now, the view hierarchy looks like the following:

[image]

One thing that is important is `NOT` to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. Need to fix constraints: after such moving of subviews, many constraints were messed up. Two important things regarding constraints in this case: remove constraints of subviews (that were previously children of the `scrollView`) to the scrollView, and set up new ones to the `UIView`; and make `scrollView` equal width to the `UIView`.